# What's meant by work resolution in reference to a LCD screen of a desktop?

Tags: display, lcd, resolution, pixels

My Acer LCD's Work Resolution is 1600*860 pixels. But I have no option to set it. I do have options 1600*900. Windows says that I am at recommended resolution 1600*900. But I see Red Shading all over the screen. Especially whenever there is black colour on the screen. Anyone knows how to fix it. These red lines shading sometimes go when i restart but most of times wont go. If high watch movies I face the same prrblem. Help me...

Comment: What's the  model of the LCD?  Is it a standard monitor or part of a laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a question about software and a question about red lines. Two questions in one...

**Question #1:** I'm not sure about the work resolution.

**Question #2:** Red shading? Sounds like your video card might be going out.

If this is a desktop, a simple resolution would be to buy a cheap-o video card (20 USD can get you a descent one for regular non-gaming needs). If you already have a video card in your desktop, take out the video card and go through the motherboard.

If it is a laptop, a graphics card replacement can be a little difficult if you are not used to working on laptops, but they have tutorials for specific models all over the internet. Just Google it...

Answer (score 1):

The only time I have come across this term was under windows and meant your screen size less the space taken up your taskbar.

Comment: 40 pixels for the height of the taskbar seems consistent with the pixel count in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded the drivers for the monitor? Some monitors that have less common native resolutions really need the drivers to tell the system the correct resolution.

However, like the others here, the red shading does not sound like anything I've ever seen related to screen resolution. It sounds either like a bad connector between the computer and the monitor, a bad monitor, or a bad video card.